# in the unit circle, names of the various points depending on the angle at the origin

Tags: trigonometry, terminology, mathematical-german

I found this image on German wikipedia, naming points related to the unit circle with letters.

[image]

Most makes sense, like **S** for *Sine*, **C** for *Cosine*, **O** for *Origin*, **P** for *Point*, **T** for *Tangent*, and **K** for *Cotangent* (in German it is *Kotangens*, and **C** is taken by *Cosine* anyways). Now what's still open is what **D** and **E** and **b** stand for. Does someone have an idea? Thanks a lot!

Background: I find it useful to have consistent naming for such things. It allows for briefer and more comprehensible descriptions. I find it of particular use when I program shaders.

Comment: Probably nothing in particular, just some available letters. Note they're just $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and don't depend on the angle at all.

Comment: I believe $E$ can mean $eins$, but this question sounds like proposal of searching something what may not exist.

Comment: **D**istance (Distanz) and **E**levation, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The $b$ stands for the German word for arc, which is $der~ Bogen$.

It is not clear to me why the letters $D$ and $E$ were chosen for the points $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$, respectively.  They could just be labels chosen since they are different from the other letters in the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

They are just $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and are not really that significant, so you don't really need to worry about them. I am not sure about what $D$ and $E$ stand for - it might be something in German (and my German is not very good to say the least). As @aschepler suggested, it might just be some available letters that mean nothing. As for $b$, it is the arc with angle $POD$